# Do we have a site for miscellaneous questions?

Tags: discussion

I wanted to ask this question, but I am unsure where to post this. It's about this [comic](http://explosm.net/comics/3566/) I've read, but I didn't get the punchline.

Maybe miscellaneous questions like these don't really deserve a site of their own from Stack Exchange. So do we have a site where we can ask miscellaneous stuff like these? Sort of a location for questions from all topics not falling into any SE site category?

Comment: Why do you need a "miscellaneous" site? Why not a site about comics?

Comment: I didn't really need a miscellaneous site. I was just asking if we have a place for questions like these (for people unsure where to post their questions). Although, can people just ask where to post their questions here at meta?

Comment: Yes, you can. That's why we have a site recommendation tag. Although for something like comic books, you'd probably want to go to [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com). Generally we'd expect programming-related site recommendations here at Meta Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll explain it for you, just this once. <kbd>F5</kbd> is the key used in Windows to refresh the view of the file explorer. The drink is very "refreshing." Get it?

In the future, though, I would check out [English Language and Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/), our site related to English and its usage. They seem to have a fair number of questions regarding jokes, puns, etc., so I don't think it'd be off-topic there.

Comment: FYI, F5 refreshes pages in web browsers too.

Comment: Arguably IE/a-browser is the main place a windows user would use/understand the F5 reference. I think it's incidental that it works in the file explorer, and is only because IE/the file explorer are two views of effectively the same thing, even though many users may not realize that.

Comment: My goodness, that cartoon is hilarious. What we really need is a site where we can share gems like that one. Hey, don't judge me—I *love* bad puns.

Comment: @AD7six I learned about `F5` in the *gasp* days before IE integration into Windows!